# Zariski Topology: $V(S)=V(\langle S\rangle)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, zariski-topology

I would like to show that $V(S)=V(<S>)$. 
I know that $S$ is a collection of polynomials from $\mathbb{P}^n$. $V(S)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : p(x)=0, \forall p\in S\}$

$\langle S\rangle=\{f_1g_1h_1+\dots+f_kg_kh_k: k\in \mathbb{N}, f_i,h_i\in \mathbb{P}^n, g\in S\}$

I have tried to take a $V(S)\subseteq V(\langle S\rangle)$ and $V(\langle S\rangle)\subseteq V(S)$ approach, but I am getting stuck. I found a proof of the proposition Here: [Proof of the proposition $V(S)=V(\langle S \rangle )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127758/proof-of-the-proposition-vs-v-langle-s-rangle?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But, I am not following it well especially since I have defined things slightly different. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated; thank you!

Comment: Yes, you have defined things differently, but the problem at hand really needs you to realize that $\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is commutative as soon as possible, if not before even starting. And thus that your two definitions do not differ at all.

Comment: What’s your definition of $fgh$,where $f,h\in \mathbb P^n, g\in S$? I also think there’s some wrong in your definition. I haven’t see definition of generated ideal as you described. It should be $f,h\in \mathbb R_[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, but since $\mathbb R$ is a field, $\mathbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is a UFD, of course commutative. So multiplying $g$ by twoside is not necessary. As for the equality, as egreg showed, it’s easy, just by definition. Another thing is that we usually consider  varieties over an algebraically closed field, say $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that, if $S\subseteq T$, then $V(T)\subseteq V(S)$. Therefore
$$
V(\langle S\rangle)\subseteq V(S)
$$
Suppose now $x\in V(S)$ and let $p\in\langle S\rangle$. By definition of $\langle S\rangle$,
$$
p=f_1g_1h_1+\dots+f_kg_kh_k
$$
where $f_1,\dots,f_k,h_1,\dots,h_k$ are suitable polynomials and $g_1,\dots,g_k\in S$. Then
$$
p(x)=f_1(x)g_1(x)h_1(x)+f_2(x)g_2(x)h_2(x)+\dots+f_k(x)g_k(x)h_k(x)=0
$$
and so $p\in V(\langle S\rangle)$.

The definition of $\langle S\rangle$ can actually be simplified, because the set you describe is the same as
$$
\{f_1g_1+\dots+f_kg_k: k\in \mathbb{N}, f_i\in \mathbb{P}^n, g\in S\}
$$
as multiplication in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is commutative.